# C++ cin read STDIN

Tags: c++, visual-c++, input, stdin, cin

How to use C++ to get all the `STDIN` and parse it?

For example, my input is

```
2
1 4
3
5 6 7
```

I want to use C++ to read the `STDIN` using cin and store the each line in an array.  So, it will be an vector/array of array of integers.

Thanks!

Comment: so what is your question or problem here? you should do your homework alone or be more specific.

Comment: This is probably the first thing any C++ book teaches.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since this isn't tagged as homework, here's a small example of reading from `stdin` using `std::vector`s and `std::stringstream`s. I added an extra part at the end also for iterating through the `vector`s and printing out the values. Give the console an `EOF` (<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>d</kbd> for *nix, <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>z</kbd> for Windows) to stop it from reading in input.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>

int main(void)
{
   std::vector< std::vector<int> > vecLines;

   // read in every line of stdin   
   std::string line;
   while ( getline(std::cin, line) )
   {
      int num;
      std::vector<int> ints;
      std::istringstream ss(line); // create a stringstream from the string

      // extract all the numbers from that line
      while (ss >> num)
         ints.push_back(num);

      // add the vector of ints to the vector of vectors         
      vecLines.push_back(ints);      
   }

   std::cout << "\nValues:" << std::endl;
   // print the vectors - iterate through the vector of vectors   
   for ( std::vector< std::vector<int> >::iterator it_vecs = vecLines.begin();
         it_vecs != vecLines.end(); ++it_vecs )
   {
      // iterate through the vector of ints and print the ints
      for ( std::vector<int>::iterator it_ints = (*it_vecs).begin();
         it_ints < (*it_vecs).end(); ++it_ints )
      {
         std::cout << *it_ints << " ";
      }

      std::cout << std::endl; // new line after each vector has been printed
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Input/Output:

```
2
1 4
3
5 6 7

Values:
2 
1 4 
3 
5 6 7
```

**EDIT:** Added a couple more comments to the code. Also note that an empty `vector`s of `int`s can be added to `vecLines` (from an empty line of input), that's intentional so that the output is the same as the input.

Answer (score 0):

```
int main () 
{
    char line[100];
    while(!cin.eof()){
        cin.getline(line, 100);
        printf("%s\n", line);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Sorry, I just wasn't sure if there's any way better than this.

Comment: There are better C++ ways.  Read it into a string instead of a char array.  Use a stringstream to parse it into your integer vector.

Answer (score 0):

This one should fit your requirement , use `istringstream` to separate the line into an array.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
        string s("A B C D E F G");
        vector<string> vec;
        istringstream iss(s);

        do
        {
                string sub;
                iss >> sub;
                if ( ! sub.empty() ) 
                        vec.push_back (sub);
        } while (iss);

        vector<string>::iterator it = vec.begin();
        while ( it != vec.end() )
        {
                cout << *it << endl;
                it ++;
        }

        return 0;
}
```